# Appending whitespace at the end of the line

Tags: c#

I need to add space at the end of line. here is the code i used.

```
string newText = searchRegex.Replace(text, newLine);
string[] strings=newText.Split('\n');
newText = string.Empty;
for (int i = 1; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    newText += strings[i].PadRight(10, '$');
    newText += "\n";
}
```

But, empty space is added at the beginning of line. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Are you sure the space isn't at the beginning of the line already? If the line has spaces then `PadRight` may not be able to do anything because each line has more than 10 characthers.

Comment: Your code would add dollar signs, not whitespace, to the end of your lines... is that just test code or something? Also, as @RePierre says, you may have whitespace already on the start of the line (it may help to see the sample set used) so maybe you should Trim() each line before padding it?

Comment: There is no empty space added at the beginning of the line. and that dollar symbol is for testing purpose

Comment: Now I have overcome this issue by using new variable for split function and I manipulated it. I got the desired result. But I dont know whether it is a right approach